# How to work with node.js and Dialogflow

Tags: python, node.js, dialogflow-es

can you show me how to work with Dialogflow with node.js. Where can I find information?

For example, here I have found one example in Python, but how to make the same in node.js?

Python code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import apiai, json
updater = Updater(token='ВАШ API ТОКЕН') # Токен API к Telegram
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def startCommand(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Привет, давай пообщаемся?')
def textMessage(bot, update):
    request = apiai.ApiAI('ВАШ API ТОКЕН').text_request() # Токен API к Dialogflow
    request.lang = 'ru' # На каком языке будет послан запрос
    request.session_id = 'BatlabAIBot' 
    request.query = update.message.text 
    responseJson = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
    response = responseJson['result']['fulfillment']['speech'] 

    if response:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=response)
    else:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text='Я Вас не совсем понял!')

start_command_handler = CommandHandler('start', startCommand)
text_message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, textMessage)

dispatcher.add_handler(start_command_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(text_message_handler)

updater.start_polling(clean=True)

updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in your quote requires apiai (second line). A good starting point is looking for those libraries and how they work. They often have example code and/or references to examples.

Take a look at https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client
or https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

A quick online search for 'dialogflow node.js' gives tons of examples, either in Youtube form, Medium articles or oter instructables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Beginner's guide to creating Chatbots using Dialogflow](https://medium.com/engineering-applozic/beginners-guide-to-creating-chatbots-using-dialogflow-f56e9f6ddaf5).

Follow the guide and you will be able to create a bot like [repofinder](http://www.topioslibraries.com/). source code is available on [github](https://github.com/AppLozic/RepoFinder-Chatbot).